# wordpress editor removing style for table when copied from google spreadsheet

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to copy the table from Google spreadsheet to wordpress editor(Tinymce). The table gets copied but remove table heading colors, background colors.

- Have also installed TinyMCE Advanced plugin.
- Have also tried following

`

```
function prevent_deleting_pTags($init){
     $init['wpautop'] = false; //had given true|false
     $init['paste_as_text'] = false;//had given true|false
     return $init;
} 
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'prevent_deleting_pTags');`
```

Is this possible in WordPress Editor. I do want to stick to wordpress editor (Tinymce)itself rather going for third party plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The table you are copying probably has a separate style sheet which is not copying over.  You are probably only copying the HTML (not the CSS styles).  That, and/or you may have existing styles overriding tables.

Comment: Yes. from view source, could see that the styles are missing. But how to copythe table from spreadsheet(Excel) with table heading color to word press editor with missing styles.

Comment: You would have to find the styles you want to utilize and copy them into your existing CSS.